# Application Insights in Net Core 2 WebApi - Share Context To Append Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

We are looking to record the username attached to every authorized request for our system in Application Insights.

The issue I'm facing is, using [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#add-request-level-properties-for-all-telemetry-items) as a guide, that it throws an `InvalidOperationException` whenever I try to access session.

```
public class PropertyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public PropertyTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!(telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry))
                return;

            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session == null || !_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.IsAvailable)
                return;

            var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
            requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["userId"] = userId?.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Throws "Session has not been configured for this application or request."

        }

    }
}
```

We get the user details out of session in the base class of every controller in our WebApi system - **is there a way to get the current request context at that point and append the userId to the Properties collection at that level of the request?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access the `RequestTelemetry` inside your controller as shown below.

```
    // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            var requestTelemetry = HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
            requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["userId"] = "myuserid"
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```